# Swapping profile information blocks based on referring site section

Tags: html, seo, user-experience

My question is about choosing the best option for users (including SEO-wise) on a site I'm currently designing.

- The site provides information on retirement villages and each village has a profile page
- Each retirement village can now post information on a property for sale / rent

**I need help deciding on the best placement for the property information:**

1. Include the property information on the *village profile page*
2. Create a separate profile page for the property information
3. Include all of the property information on the *property results page*

### 1. Include the property on the *village profile page*

This seems the strongest option for SEO as both users looking for village or property information head to the same page.

On the other hand, this means I'll need to swap the position of some of the content depending on the referring page (see diagram below). This may create some confusion as the page content changes position based on the referring section. It just feels...  messy.

[image: Website flow diagram for option 1]

### 2. Create separate profile page for the property information

I'm trending towards this option as it presents a page focused on the property information they have selected.

This option may cause less users to view the *village profile page*.

[image: Website flow diagram for option 2]

### 3. Include all of the property information on the *property results page*

Going with option 3 will allow users to quickly see the property information but it'll increase the complexity of the results page.

This option may cause less users to view the *village profile page*.

Any help choosing an option would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If option 1 is the best SEO option, and the usability can still be very good, why not use a querystring variable to determine which content has priority, and instruct Google and yahoo/Bing to ignore the querystring via webmaster tools and a site map and/or no follows on the non-default version?

Comment: Hi Jim, thanks for your suggestion. Using a querystring does sound like the best method and another bonus is that it's capable of placing the property at the top of the list (if there's more than one).

Comment: I'm still keen on more opinions, let me know what you think :)

Comment: This is one of the best off topic questions I've seen.  BTW, if you have questions about seo strategies, they are welcome on [webmasters.se].  StackOverflow is for questions having to do with programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If option 1 is the best SEO option, and the usability can still be very good, I'd suggest using a querystring variable to determine which content has priority, and instructing Google and yahoo/Bing to ignore the querystring via webmaster tools and a site map and/or no follows on the non-default link version.

*note: moved from comment and rephrased as it seems to be the best and only answer so far*